# problema con doble if else

Tags: python

```
def Codificar(num):
 queda = num
 suma = 0

 while queda > 0:
  digit = queda % 10
  if digit<=5:
      suma += digit*7
  else :
      suma += (digit - 1)
      if suma%2 != 0:
         return suma ** 3
      else:
         return suma * 1000



numero = int(input("Ingrese un número de 8 dígitos: "))
while numero // 10000000 == 0:
     print ("su numero codificado es: ",Codificar(numero))
```

Hola, estoy intentando hacer que este código funcione, pero no logro que lo haga, la idea es ingresar un número de 8 dígitos y a partir de este, codificarlo de la siguiente forma. Para cada dígito: si el dígito es menor o igual a 5 es necesario multiplicar este dígito por 7.
Caso contrario se le debe restar 1 a este dígito.
Cada uno de los dígitos codificados debe ser sumado generando un nuevo número.
Si el número es impar, se deben elevar el número al cubo. En cambio, si es par se deben agregar tres ceros al final del número.
No sé cual es el error. Gracias.

Comment: El error por lo que veo estimado está en tu restricción del while, en el fondo si el número en división entera es distinto de 0 no hará nada. Define parametros de prueba para ayudarte con tu duda

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La lógica general de tu código está bien, pero por lo que entendí del problema, necesita algunas correcciones

1. La verificación de par/impar debe ser después de que hayas terminado de iterar sobre los dígitos. Debe estar fuera del while, no dentro del else.
2. Nunca modificas el valor de la variable `queda` lo que hace que ese while loop sea infinito.
3. No entiendo el propósito del while de la penúltima línea

El siguiente código implementa las correcciones que menciono y mantiene las otras partes de tu solución

```
def Codificar(num):
  queda = num
  suma = 0

  while queda > 0:
    digit = queda % 10
    if digit<=5:
      suma += digit*7
    else:
      suma += (digit - 1)
    queda = int(queda / 10) ## esto elimina el último digito en cada iteración

  if suma%2 != 0:
      return suma ** 3
  else:
      return suma * 1000

numero = int(input("Ingrese un número de 8 dígitos: "))
print ("su numero codificado es:", Codificar(numero))
```